# DownloadRangeToByteArray method in CloudBlockBlob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I'm using Azure SDK v2.1.0.0. I found a method in CloudBlockBlob class called DownloadRangeToByteArray, but unfortunately I can't find any documentation about it in the online MSDN?

any idea about it's usage, constraints, thread safety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the GitHub repository for Azure Storage Client Library https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/583799d5238ffb72b8d9244604558a83ed4372f8/microsoft-azure-api/Services/Storage/Lib/DotNetCommon/Blob/ICloudBlob.cs:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Downloads the contents of a blob to a byte array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="target">The target byte array.</param>
    /// <param name="index">The starting offset in the byte array.</param>
    /// <param name="blobOffset">The starting offset of the data range, in bytes.</param>
    /// <param name="length">The length of the data range, in bytes.</param>
    /// <param name="accessCondition">An <see cref="AccessCondition"/> object that represents the access conditions for the blob.</param>
    /// <param name="options">A <see cref="BlobRequestOptions"/> object that specifies any additional options for the request.</param>
    /// <param name="operationContext">An <see cref="OperationContext"/> object that represents the context for the current operation.</param>
    /// <returns>The total number of bytes read into the buffer.</returns>
    int DownloadRangeToByteArray(byte[] target, int index, long? blobOffset, long? length, AccessCondition accessCondition = null, BlobRequestOptions options = null, OperationContext operationContext = null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the delay, there was an issue in the internal publishing chain that caused the docs to be held up. They should be out shortly.

In the mean time the GitHub info above is correct the idea of this method is that it lets you specify a range of the blob bytes (rather than the entire blob) to download directly into a byte array at a given index.